# jQuery Mask plugin - Can I send the unmasked input value without unmasking the input itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, masking

I've been using the jQuery Mask plugin (https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) and I want to send the unmasked value when submitting the form. I was using this code to do it:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('.mask').unmask();
});
```

However, I also use some JS form validation which returns false on error so the form doesn't submit. This still removes the mask, so after a validation error, all the masks on the form are gone.

Is there a way I can either send the unmasked values when submitting without removing the masks from the inputs or reapply all the masks after a submit error?